# Angular 6/typescript datetime stamp a file

Tags: typescript, datetime-format

I am generating an xlsx file and would like to append date/time stamp to it. But the format I am getting ( `myfilename1549387892303.xlsx`) with the following code doesn't reflect today's date and time in a readable format.

```
myfilename + "_" + new Date().getTime() + ".xlsx"
```

Please guide what is an appropriate way to achieve this

Comment: What is the date format that you want?

Comment: Doesn't really matter - just indication of date and time (to sec) the file was created

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how to handle the time. The same way you can add the date later on in the format you want

```
function addZero(i) {
  if (i < 10) {
    i = "0" + i;
  }
  return i;
}

function myFunction() {
  var d = new Date();
  var h = addZero(d.getHours());
  var m = addZero(d.getMinutes());
  var s = addZero(d.getSeconds());

  myfilename + "_" + h + "-" + m + "-" + s + ".xlsx"
}
```

EDIT. Your code:

```
getDateTime(): string { 
    var d = new Date(); 
    var mo = this.addZero(d.getMonth() + 1); 
    var yr = this.addZero(d.getFullYear()); 
    var dt = this.addZero(d.getDate()); 
    var h = this.addZero(d.getHours()); 
    var m = this.addZero(d.getMinutes()); 
    var s = this.addZero(d.getSeconds()); 

    return ("_" + mo + '-' + dt + '-' + yr + '-' + h + "-" + m + "-" + s + ".xlsx"); 
}
```

Comment: Modified code to add month,date and year. However, month is being shown as -1 giving result as myFilename_01-05-2019-14-26-44.xlsx. What is an appropriate way to handle this?

   getDateTime(): string {
       var d = new Date();
       var mo = this.addZero(d.getMonth());
       var yr = this.addZero(d.getFullYear());
       var dt = this.addZero(d.getDate());
       var h = this.addZero(d.getHours());
       var m = this.addZero(d.getMinutes());
       var s = this.addZero(d.getSeconds());

    return ("_" + mo + '-' + dt + '-' + yr + '-' + h + "-" + m + "-" + s + ".xlsx");
}

Comment: adding 1 to month works, but is that the correct way to do it?

Comment: Yes it is, as month is unfortunately represented by the range of 0 to 11. So January is actually month 0 instead of 1.

Comment: I copied your code to my answer. From my point of view you did it correct. There might be some frameworks that could do the formatting for you. But this is mostly too much unnecessary code. What you did is a fast and concise way to solve this task. Well done. -- Please, don't forget to mark this answer as solution if it helped you.